# Nesting messages when serializing using protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have a requirement to produce protocol buffer output in this form:

```
message TimeSeries {
    message Point {
        required int64 DateTime = 1;
        required double Value = 2;
    }
    repeated Point Points = 3;
}
```

In C#, no matter whether I define the TimeSeries and Point classes separately or with Point as a nested class, I cannot get the resultant output from calling Serializer.GetProto to produce this hierarchy.

This was what I assumed would produce the desired results:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class TimeSeries 
{
    [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true)]
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Point
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true)]
        public Int64? DateTime { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = true)]
        public Double? Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Instead I get:

```
message Point {
   required int64 DateTime = 1;
   required double Value = 2;
}
message TimeSeries {
   repeated Point Points = 1;
}
```

I am new to protocol buffers and protobuf-net, so may well be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema-generation code currently produces flat output; if you want nested output, you can simply edit the generated schema.